# Recyclerview each row inflate layout in runtime

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i am using Recyclerview to display list .

each row have one more sublayout which is define in dynamically/run time .
sublayout contains textview and image .
 like 1st row can have 1 sublayout where as 2nd have 3 sublayout .

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {

    for (int i = 0; i < data; i++) {
        final View c = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row, null);


        holder.inner.addView(c);

    }


}
```

but this give 1st time proper but when i scroll it shuffle inside layout count

what is the best way to have dynamically layout inside each row

Comment: how i can do it ? like each row can have n number of one sublayout . sublayout have textview

Answer (score 0):

You could implement two custom views for your data, the header view view the main rows and a child view with sub layouts. Set a type flag in your model to detect whether data is header or child and inflate the different layouts accordingly. Check for type in your adapter by overwriting the

int getItemViewType(int position);